# Determining properties available for Spring Beans?

Tags: java, spring

In the Spring Framework, how do you determine what "properties" and other related values are available to be set in the context.xml file(s)?   For example, I need to set the isolation level of a TransactionManager.   Would that be:

```
<property name="isolation" value="SERIALIZABLE" />
<property name="isolation_level" value="Isolation.SERIALIZABLE" />
```

or some other values?

Comment: do you mean .properties file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each bean represents a class, which you can easily find by `class=""` attribute. Now you simply open JavaDoc or source code of that class and look for all setters (methods following `setFooBar()` naming convention). You strip `set` prefix and un-capitalize the first character, making it `fooBar`. These are your properties.

In your particular case you are probably talking about [`PlatformTransactionManager`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html) and various implementations it has.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the properties into . properties file is a good way of handling.

First define a properties file in your project structure. It is better to put .properties file with the same directory as spring applicationContext.xml.

Your properties file may seem like this :

```
isolation = "SERIALIZABLE"
isolation_level = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE
```

You can access this properties file by defining a spring bean like :

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location" value="classpath:YourProperties.properties"/>

</bean>
```

Finally you can access these properties inside Spring beans like :

```
  <bean id="BeanName" class="YourClass">

        <property name="PropertyName1" value="${isolation}"/>

        <property name="PropertyName" value="${isolation_level}"/>


    </bean>
```

There is another way to inject these values using annotations.